# Subliminal Persuasion: best chances of success

Tags: perception, decision-making, priming

A lot of people are skeptic about the impact of subliminal messages. Good research and experiments on this topic are hard to find.

Therefore, I want to execute an experiment on this topic. To do this right, I'm curious what the best ways are to influence someone's decision making via subliminal messages / priming.

Does anyone have experience or helpful research that will increase the chance of successfully persuading people subliminally in my experiment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Has there been any serious research on subliminal messaging?](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/8203/has-there-been-any-serious-research-on-subliminal-messaging)

Comment: That question is way broader than this one (as the auther sais himself). Also it wasn't answered.

Comment: I vaguely remember there was research that found that subliminal messages showed effects to someone decision only when he/she doesn't have any initial preferences/choices (somewhat neutral). It was explained in a psychology book, back when I was still in university (perhaps 7 years ago), but I don't remember the details.

Comment: @Nono Thanks! I suspected that. This is an interesting point I think.

Comment: @MaxdeMooij Have you read the resources [on the related (duplicate) question](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/8203/21)? _"I'm curious what the best ways are to influence someone's decision making"_ Surely if they study subliminal messages they will describe this in their methodology?

Comment: "Good research and experiments on this topic are hard to find." and then " I'm curious what the best ways are to influence someone's decision making via subliminal messages / priming." "Best ways" based on what given that you say no "good research" exists?

Comment: @Fizz You're changing my words. I said "hard to find". Not that good research doesn't exist. If someone knows a valid and unbiased research with statistical significance, then that is very helpful. Also I'm asking for people's experiences. Please consider to read my question and your reply again. If you have anything of value to the topic as stated in the question, I would love to know.

Comment: Fair enough... and mea culpa. I was negatively influenced by the other (linked) question as well... because that one seems even more unclear even though it has substantially better background than yours. You should definitely look at the meta-analysis mentioned there (Trappey) for possible clues; it doesn't look it's done a moderator analysis though (with respect to what study design is likely to produce what result.).

Comment: @Fizz Thanks for the effort, I'll dig into the results!

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of "Hail Mary" answers: there's a recent [(2016) paper by Ruch et al.](https://doi.org/10.1093/nc/niw013) claiming unprecedented results:

> Subliminal influence did not significantly decay if probed after 25 versus 15 min. This is unprecedented evidence of the longevity and impact of subliminal messages on conscious, rational decision-making.

You could try to replicate their experiment(s).

Answer (score 0):

*Edited:*
Making sure to make a path of trailing the information to the commons that is able to redirect from the beginning point as subliminal, i.e. I have reported there is a location point where to find the hidden message then to another hidden spot where the message resides then the person gets the message and can claim a reward. If you can find that person who can follow these then these are the queues of seeing how willingly the effort comes along with it then can have another person who is in good connection with the person and try to see if he/she picks up the information without looking consciously, and grab information from the person that's connected too. All in all, it's trial and error for an individual person and it takes a lot of time and patience. This is all just an idea.

They could also be on some particular substance or have higher knowledge along with coordination and balance with the psych. They may remain unconsciously knowing something is particularly there; it’s very hard to pick up the sensibility in which, is a very hard deal to break through to find the right person. It is in fact very wise to keep things subliminal as possible to find the subliminal person because it attracts them and to remain subliminal. Once you find the particular one that seem to be unconscious of but really is consciously aware. The person doesn't have to say what or look at your body but in their possible peripheral vision. Sometimes you just can't rule it out, some are just too good to be true; some are way too good to be true. It's in some sort of higher intelligence to think before they react. And typically intuitive personage are capable of this but not all are good responders/followers. 
***1**

> Also it's like a person has trained itself into a unconcious and sub
>   concious state to not react. But is conciously able to react as if it
>   were internally.

As for a matter of fact I have for a very long time didn't hear a sound until the age of 3 then picked up on hearing. This has made me become effective at my picking up skills in a very correct way. I started formulating my own hand signs to my parents until they have found I was deaf. I was typically not recognizing my hearing senses so it allowed me to balance my sense over sight vs hearing. ***2**

***1** https://www.psychologytoday.com/articles/200705/gut-almighty

***2** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prelingual_deafness

*Added:* I’m sorry I've lost track in the post about the autism part scratch that. Lost senses from the early age 'till the age of 3 are capable of mastering to accommodate the other senses to a heightened level. The overall senses of the brain is training itself to accommodate the loss senses. Such as like the (anti-)phantom sense, possibly become the 6th sense. I.e a person with lost sense regain it’s natural balance. I can relate to this book. It's in .PDF format ***3**

Your brain changes with every experience: every sight, every sound, every touch, every thought, every emotion. It then interprets future experiences based on the past experiences. But a person with hearing disability can't pick up the subliminal messages as well as near perfect hearing. ***4**

Autism puts things together in a complex puzzle.***5**

So with this attributed with number **3* & number **2*. It can put all the puzzles together and fills in the missing puzzles as a dummy puzzle to accommodate then this goes back to number **1*

I tried to render this question for the right answer as rational as possible lol, I sense there is something there but not quite understood right. It is a plugin and play kind of deal with there are other things I can recognize is there but there's no way how I can precisely explain or to even convey in this language. It's an onomatopoeia along with transpositioning the language involved and it may seem irrational when really it's rational. Trying to keep all of this rational as possible.

***3** http://richardlouv.com/images/uploads/excerpt-the-nature-principle-richard-louv.pdf

***4** http://ilslearningcorner.com/2015-06-the-age-when-your-childs-brain-stops-learning/

***5** http://childdevelopmentinfo.com/child-psychology/autism-aspergers/

Comment: Thanks for taking the effort to answer the question and assemble sources.  I still wonder what the connection between the last 2 sources and the topic is.

Comment: Okay, tried to break it down more for you, not sure if this can be understood. I like this question a lot and got me thinking. :)

Comment: It's a very interesting topic indeed! :-) Thanks for clarifying the answer, I'm going to take the time to fully break it down for myself again.